# Tangent space to a level curve

Tags: differential, tangent-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be an open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Let $f:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ a differentiable function, and $X=\{ x\in \Omega \, | \, f(x)=c\}$ a level curve. If $v$ is a tangent vector to $X$ in $a$, there exists $\gamma : ]-\varepsilon , \varepsilon [ \to A$ a function of class $C^1$ such that $\gamma(0)=a$ and $\gamma'(0)=v$.
The function $f \circ \gamma$ is constant, hence $(f\circ\gamma)'=0$, which is equivalent to :
\begin{equation} \mathrm{d}f_{\gamma(t)}(\gamma'(t))=0 \end{equation}
For $t=0$, we have $\mathrm{d}f_a(v)=0$, so every tangent vector of $X$ in $a$ is in the kernel of $\mathrm{d}f_a$.
I would like to know if we have the converse : is every vector in the kernel of $\mathrm{d}f_a$ tangent to $X$ in $a$?

Comment: You should assume at the outset that $c$ is a regular value, so that the kernel set is a smooth submanifold. For this, yes, the converse is true by a dimension count.

Comment: ^I meant level set, not kernel set

Comment: So it's sufficient that $\mathrm{d} f_a$ is non-zero ? (a non-zero linear form is surjective)

Comment: More precisely you need $df_x$ to be non-zero for all $x$ such that $f(x)=c$.